# Error while installing node-oracledb

Tags: node.js, node-oracledb

I have a simple node.js server and some app running on it, that should connect to Oracle database. For that reason I decided to use `node-oracledb` driver, but I'm having some problems with installation. I followed instructions on [Oracle webpage](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-931127) and those on [github](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md#instwin), but I still get an error below.

My environment configuration:

- Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bit
- node.js v6.4.0
- npm v3.10.3
- MS Visual Studio 2013 Community edition
- Python v2.7.12
- Oracle Instant Client (basic + SDK) v12.1.0.2.0

Node, Python and Oracle Instant Client folders are included in PATH variable. OCI_LIB_DIR and OCI_INC_DIR are also set according to github instructions.

Here's the problem: when I execute command `npm install oracledb -g`, the following error occurs:

```
> oracledb@1.11.0 install C:\Users\pr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ora
cledb
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\pr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\oracledb>if not defined npm_c
onfig_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\
\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )

Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Users\pr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxp
roj(20,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props"
 was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, a
nd that the file exists on disk.
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_proces
s.js:204:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\pr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\oracledb
gyp ERR! node -v v6.4.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "oracledb" "-g"
npm ERR! node v6.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! oracledb@1.11.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the oracledb@1.11.0 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the oracledb package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs oracledb
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls oracledb
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\pr\Development\Visual Studio 2013\npm-debug.log
```

I don't really know where to look at for a solution. What could cause that error? Are there any known incompatibilities between node/oracle client/python?

One more thing: github instructions say:

> Make sure the Microsoft Visual Studio environment variables are set
>   appropriately. Use set PATH and verify it contains your Visual Studio
>   paths. If they are not set, use vcvars64.bat (or vcvars.bat if you
>   building with 32-bit binaries) to set the environment.

Which VS environment variables should be set and which VS paths should be contained in PATH exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Modules like oracledb or node-oracledb needs compilations. Compilation requires software like C compiler, Python etc.

I was facing the same issue with oracldb module. follow below instructions and it works like charm.

https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-931127

Answer (score 0):

try updating npm to the latest version:

```
npm install -g npm
```

if it still doesn't work, try including your VS version like so:

```
npm install oracledb --msvs_version=2013
```